# quick way to check for duplicate values in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios4

I need to quickly check to see if I have some duplicate values in CoreData. I am doing some background syncing and occasionally a dupe makes it into my system.

I have a ManufacturerID and an ItemID and I cannot have a duplicate value for both, example of bad data:

```
ManufacturerID   ItemID
35               IT001
35               IT001
```

So I would just want to know if that happened and maybe get a list of those ItemID's, then I need a way to figure out how to get rid of the dupes but this is a good start.

I just need a fast method figure out if they exist or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my app I have a SynchManager that using NSoperations performs synch in background and store new records in the persistent sqlite store only if not alredy stored.
Basically what I do is:

1. execute a fetch request which retrieves a collections of stored ids (in my case these ids are strings representing urls)
2. before insert a new object in the store I call a method like "**shouldImportObject:**", which basically test that the url is not already stored in the database. This is a simplified implementation sample:

   ```
   for (id objectID in ids) {
     if ([objectID isEqual:objectToImport.objectID]) {
        return NO;
     }
   }

   return YES;
   ```

Comment: problem with that is I have possibly 50,000+ records to go through.  Theoretically the first time I get data I do not check for duplicates (this is my problem), from then on out I do a fetch request to see if the item exists but this would be so slow on initial importing of data, seems a little crazy and would cause a lot of disk io.

Comment: I think you just turned a light on for me!  DOH - I can check to see if it is empty - LOL @ myself